# FB share plugin, does not show unless page is reloaded, angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

I am trying to use the facebook share plugin. It works fine if I reload the page, but if i go to the page without reloading then the "share button" does not appear. I have tried moving the facebook sdk code into my template and into the head but neither seem to do the trick. Any ideas?

this is the fb code that I have right below the opening  tag

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
```

where i implement in my html template 
the fbUrl is defined in my controller

```
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="{{fbUrl}}" data-layout="button" id='fb-share'></div>
```

Comment: What's with `data-  layout`? Also, you appear to be loading the Facebook JavaScript SDK twice

Comment: they were typos, my bad

Comment: Try re-parsing the page for FB tags ~ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the function runs immediately. It's an [immediately invocable function expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). If you put it in the head, it runs before any of the rest of the document. The only (probably) safe place to put it would be at the end of your document, before the body tag, when all the html elements have been loaded.

If you notice, one of the call is to `getElementById` but no elements are loaded if you put that into the head and the ID element might not have been loaded if you put it any place else.

Comment: It's not in the `<head>` (unless that `<div>` is too)

Comment: @Phil He said he tried moving into the head. If he has the div in that, too, that's another whole can of worms. Still, if he has it anywhere near the top, problems may come about.

Comment: I just tried adding the fb code to just before the end of my </body> tag and after the </body> and the same issue was persisting. It would work if I reloaded it but not if i just navigated to the page. Do you think a directive would be necessary or are there ways around that?

Comment: @Billy Not after the </body> tag. Before it. If you are needing to reload, then there are other things taking place and being loaded at different times and there's no way to help you with that here.